# disable infobox when taking screenshots with xfce screenshooter

Tags: xfce, screenshot

I want to take screenshots very quickly and when I press the print key xfce-screenshooter takes a screenshot and saves it automatically in my pictures folder. The problem is every time I take a screenshot there pops up an infobox on the screen which says I have taken a screenshot. So when I take the next screenshot the box is on the screenshot picture which is annoying. I haven´t found a way to disable this feature. Does anyone has any idea how I can disable this feature so my pictures are free of this infobox?

Comment: Did you find this? https://docs.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-notifyd/preferences

Comment: Yes that was what I was looking for. I just have set it to do not disturb.

Answer (score 1):

xfce's Notification Plugin has various options for controlling notifications, including a "Do Not Disturb" mode.

Add the plugin to a panel if it's not already there.

Comment: where do I find this plugin ?

Comment: Right-click in a panel, move the cursor down to the Panel sub-menu, click on *Add New Items...*.   Start typing "notif" in the search field and you'll see the Notification Plugin.  Select it and click the *Add* button.

Comment: Is this link: https://docs.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-notifyd/preferences -- from an [earlier comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741786/disable-infobox-when-taking-screenshots-with-xfce-screenshooter#comment1409406_741786) the plugin? If so, consider editing a link into the post? Thanks!

Comment: @JeffSchaller no, that's xfce's full notifications setting dialog.   The panel plugin shows a log of the most recent notifications when you click on it (whether they popped up or not).  More relevantly, it also has a quick & easy "Do Not Disturb" ON/OFF switch, as well as a link to the full settings dialog.  You can see what the panel plugin looks like at https://docs.xfce.org/apps/notifyd/start#panel_plugin

Answer (score 0):

First go to XFCE Settings Manager in the Applications menu, then Settings, and then Settings Manager, then click on Keyboard then Application Shortcuts, look for `xfce4-screenshooter -f` and click edit, then in the Command field add this option at the end `--no-popup`. Press Ok and it should work

Comment: doesn´t work because with this option it doesn´t take any screenshot at all.